# What are JSDoc @type curly braces for?

Tags: javascript, syntax, jsdoc, curly-braces

The JSDoc `@type` tag allows specification of a variable type, such as `/** @type {Number} */`. However I've also see `/** @type Number */` without the curly braces, and it seems equally valid.

[Use JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html) has an example both with and without the curly braces, but doesn't discuss the difference. The [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types) documentation implies that all declarations must have curly braces, but doesn't specify what happens if they don't.

Are the curly braces important? If so, why? And if not, should I use them or not?

Comment: Looks like [http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html] doesn't have a braceless-example anymore. But personally, I think the braceless syntax is much more readable by the parser in my head.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My best guess is that the curly braces are there for the parser, as some type specs can have spaces in them.

eg. An object with string keys and number values:

```
{Object.<string, number>}
```

Depending on the parser a simple type (eg string) may not need the curly braces as the parser will read the first whitespace as the end of the type declaration.

edit: Further reading suggests that the curly brackets are required, so omitting them is an error, BUT some (if not most/all) parsers will forgive sloppy type definitions if they can be handled as above.

tldr: They are important, but you can get away without using them in some cases.

Comment: As per @Lambart's comment, I don't know if this is still the case, but it's the best answer by default!

Comment: What further reading suggests curly brackets are required? Some pieces of the official JSDoc documentation do not use them, e.g. http://usejsdoc.org/tags-augments.html

Comment: @Alicia: from https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html: _You can also include the parameter's type, **enclosed in curly brackets**, and a description of the parameter._